# Should I use generic foreign key with Django, and how?

Tags: database, django, foreign-keys, comments

I have php web programming background, and new to Django. I am helping my brother to build an online system to manage inventory, and I've got a database design & coding problem recently. Needing help!

How to attach a "comments" table to 1 or more tables?

That is, I have a set of tables of "possible products", "inventory", "suppiler", etc. I want to attach a "comments" to each of them, where the "comments" holds all the comment records of them. Therefore, I think I should make a generic "comment" table to hold all the comments of products, inventory, suppiler. Is that right?

### Conceptual models of my tables:

possible_products

```
id: int (pk)
name: varchar
url: varchar
price: decimal
created_at: datetime
updated_at: datetime
```

comments

```
id: int (pk)
parent_id: int (fk)
content: text
author: int (fk)
table: char (which the table this comment belongs to)
created_at: datetime
updated_at: datatime
```

My problem is, when "possible_products" table is the parent of "comment", then a foreign key of the parent (id number) is stored in the "comment" table in order to link up them.

However, how about the fk of the "inventory" table and the "suppiler" table? It should not be that: I create 2 more columns of "inventory_id" nor "suppiler_id" in "comments" table. (That is, I should not create the 4th column when I want to link up the 4th parent table.)

So, Should I use generic foreign key of Django? (so that, my "comment" table design is right.) And how to use/implement it?

Or, should I / Is it better to make an intermediate table with foreign key to link up "possible products"/"inventory"/"sellers" and "comments" ?(on design...like a many-to-many relationship)

P.S. I mainly develop the system in Django Admin. With Python 3.4 & Django 1.7rc2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't be thinking in terms of database columns: you should be thinking in terms of Django models.

This is indeed exactly what generic relationships are for. Rather than a foreign key from Comment to each of the individual models, you have one foreign key to the ContentType model - which identifies model types, not instances - and an object_id field which stores the actual ID of the relevant model. This is all explained well in the [generic relations documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1).

*Note*: If your model will be linked to a very specific and limited set of 'parent' models, it may be simpler to just add a foreign key for each model it's linked to.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I've read the generic relations documentation. However, it's very complicated and I don't understand...Could you mind to show me how to use it?

Comment: The page I linked to has an *exact example* of what to do: both a code snippet and then detailed step-by-step instructions. What exactly are you having trouble with?